# Get the largest value from the array in JS or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using flow chart lib I’m plotting a graph. Below is the `x` and `y` coordinates of the graph as an array.

```
var plottingPoints  = [[0, 3], [4, 8], [8, 5], [9, 23], [10, 2]];
```

I just need to pick largest value of the `y` coordinate (ie 23). Please need support of expertise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var plottingPoints  = [[0, 3], [4, 8], [8, 5], [9, 23], [10, 2]];
var length = plottingPoints.length;
var maxY = -Infinity;
for(var i = 0; i < length; i++)
    maxY = Math.max(plottingPoints[i][1], maxY);
```

Answer (score 2):

In new browsers you can make use of ES5's [`.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method of arrays. Also, `Math.max` returns the highest value of all arguments:

```
// calculate max value of an array of numbers
Math.max.apply(null, plottingPoints.map(function(element) {
                                            // return y coordinate
                                            return element[1];
                                        }));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var t=plottingPoints[0];
$(plottingPoints  ).each (function (i,n){

if (n[1]>t[1]) t=n;

});
```

now , t[1] - is your answer